# How to count the number of vowels in a string without a function wrapper

Tags: python, string

I've currently solving a MIT undergrad problem in Python 3.5.
The goal is to write a Python script counting and printing the number of vowels in a string containing only lower-case letters without using a function wrapper or even a function definition (stated in the assignment, weird ?).

```
def vowels_count(s):
    i=0
    counter = 0
    while(s[i] != " "):
        if s[i] == "a" or s[i] == "e" or s[i] == "i" or s[i] == "o" or s[i]   == "u":
            counter += 1
        i = i + 1
    return(counter)
```

I have two problems:
1/ first of, my own code using a while do structure meets a problem with the use of the index navigating from the first character to the last one. The debugger says: index out of range
2/ finally, if I have to comply with the MIT instructions, I would not be able to do anything in a single-line code without defining a function.

Thanks for your support

Why is this version not correct on the string index i ?

```
def vowels_count_1(s):
    i = 0
    counter = 0
      while(s[i] != ""):
        if s[i] == "a" or s[i] == "e" or s[i] ==  "i" or s[i] == "o" or s[i] == "u":
          counter += 1
      i += 1
    print("Number of vowels: " + str(counter))
```

Comment: Thanks people, I really appreciate your feedback. Very supportive and helpful, really.

Comment: I really like the different solutions you've suggested: a lambda expression, a functional definition, the use of the in operator in a for loop limiting the use of useless iterations/code. Thanks, vive Stack Overflow !

Comment: As in chess, I'm doing some variations analysis of a set of candidate algorithms for the vowels counter in a string s.

Comment: I have tried to improve my quick, dirty, blunter-added version using a while loop but I got an error message saying the string index gets out of range while iterating:

Answer (score 6):

You can use the condition of `i` being less than the length of your string to break out of the while loop. I also recommend the easier approach of just checking if the letter at `s[i]` is in a string composed of vowels:

```
def vowels_count(s):
    i = 0
    counter = 0
    while i < len(s):
        if s[i] in 'aeiou':
            counter += 1
        i += 1
    return counter
```

If you wanted to do this in one line, you could use the length of a list comprehension:

```
counter = len([c for c in s if c in 'aeiou'])
```

Comment: Instead of sending a `list` to `len`, it's more efficient to send a generator expression to `sum` with `sum(c in 'aeiou' for c in s)`. (Also, use either "composed of" or "comprising," not both.)

Comment: Though more efficient, I personally find it less readable since it involves knowing that `True == 1` and that booleans may be summed. It seems a bit too obscure to show someone new to Python - and this seems like a simple enough situation where I would prefer understandability over performance.

Answer (score 1):

As you learn more and more you'll be able to count the vowels in one line using `sum` and a generation expression.

You could fix your loop `while i < len(s)`, i.e. up to the length of the string, but much better is just to *iterate* over the sequence of characters we call "string".

```
for ch in s:
    if ch == 'a' or ...
```

No indices needed. No `i`.

If you have learned the `in` operator already, you could simplify the test.

---

Without a function probably means this:

```
s = "the string"
# your code here
print("vowel count:", counter)
```

But I'm not sure ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an one line solution:

```
reduce(lambda t, c  : (t + 1) if c in 'aeiou' else t, s.lower(),  0)
```